# Monogenic orders in number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given a CM-field $K$ (not Galois) and an algebraic integer $\alpha$. Suppose $\beta$ is a conjugate of $\alpha$ that lies in $K$. Define the order $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha, \beta]$.

Do you know some sufficient conditions (e.g. on the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$) to ensures that $\mathcal{O}$ is monogenic?